# Messenger Broadcast API Not Sending Message to Users With Role in Development App

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Ok, so, I'm stuck with a conundrum here with Facebook's Messenger Broadcast API...

I'm sending labeled broadcast messages via a Test version of a Facebook app I have. Everything works as expected if I send a broadcast message to my PSID, but when I send it to myself + another person, the other person does not receive it.

In the Broadcast API page, under 'permissions' it states:

> Apps in Development Mode, are restricted to message people that have a role in the app.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Connected the test app to the Facebook page of the app;
- Added the other person as an Admin of the page;
- Gave the person a role in the test app (Tester) + made sure the role invitation was accepted;
- Got the page approved for Subscription Messaging.

I really don't get why he is not receiving the broadcast message. This is what happens:

1. A broadcast label is created;
2. Both our PSID's are added to the label;
3. A Message Creative is created;
4. The broadcast message is sent using the label + message creative ID;
5. After a few moments I receive the broadcast message, but he does not.

If I check the broadcast insights via /insights/messages_sent, it says that it sent the broadcast to only 1 PSID. I'm not sure why it seems to ignore my friend's PSID, even though he has all the necessary roles in the page/test app.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something here? Any insight is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that might be running into this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1193413084170453/

I decided to make a bug report and after a bit of back and forth with Darija from Facebook, it got assigned to the engineering team — therefore, this is a bug and not a mistake on my side (despite driving me insane).

Hopefully, they'll stir up a fix for this :)